# Play a Video from specific duration Unity3D

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, ogg

I have a problem in streaming ogg video files which are hosted on a server. I want to stream the video from x amount of seconds. I am able to play video from starting point using MovieTexture.

But I am not able to control the video. That is seeking a video.

If I can't do anything on client (unity3d player), is there a way to tell server to give frames starting with x seconds using WWW or any other way?

Please help me. I don't why Unity, a game engine giant is not supporting this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://youtu.be/CuFLaSqNvQk?t=1m53s <= see this? It is like youtube call to start the streaming at 1 min and 53 sec.

You will need to code php GET method or depends on what coding your site is using to start the streaming.

I usually don't use the WWW streaming for game assets since you will need to have a server that does not 95% load fail.

Why don't you use Assets bundle instead. As it is made for this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks @Aizen. The URL works in the browser. Now I am embedding a web page in Unity scene which plays this video I am thinking of streaming asset bundles instead. Is it possible to stream a video using asset bundles? That too from a specific point of of time iin a video? If you have any idea on that please let me know.